# Is there a method to migrate data from oracle to postgres database for Bonita?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, jboss, database-migration, bonita

I have a java application with **BonitaBPMCommunity-6.4.1-JBoss-7.1.1** with oracle database. I want to migrate this oracle 11.2.0 EE bonita database in postgres 10 bonita database.
I proceeded with a manual migration with the ora2pg tool but I have doubts about scheduled jobs.

In fact at startup I got the following errors

```
15:19:39,812 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016037: Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource XAResourceRecord < resource:null, txid:< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a80109:-503e5c8c:5f117671:9adc2, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a80109:-503e5c8c:5f117671:9adc6, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/bonitaDS >, heuristic: TwoPhaseOutcome.FINISH_OK, product: PostgreSQL/10.13 (Ubuntu 10.13-1.pgdg18.04+1), jndiName: java:jboss/datasources/bonitaDS com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord@7b085ae5 >
15:19:39,815 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016038: No XAResource to recover < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a80109:-503e5c8c:5f117671:9adc2, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a80109:-503e5c8c:5f117671:9adc6, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/bonitaDS >
```

Solutions are described in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221033

In any case, is there anyone who has faced the same problem and what procedure has been carried out?
Has the bonita been checked for correct functioning after the migration of data from oracle to postgres?

**Edit**
Since in bars I have specific connectors for oracle db I changed them with those for postgresql db under /bonita/server/ folder. But when I start, the server recreates the

```
BonitaBPMCommunity-6.4.1-JBoss-7.1.1/bonita/server/platform/tmp/bonita_engine_9663@gi5/local/PROCESS/6202952572871618860
```

folder with original oracle connectors.
Where do you get the connector jars from?

Comment: Hi @sunrelax, the error you are getting is because you have some XA transactions pending and Jboss thinks it has to recover them. Did you try to remove the content of the data folder as suggested in the thread ?

Comment: Hi Roberto, yes, I removed the reported files but I don't know is it correct? However I am doing other checks on the scheduled jobs.